# Function to find proceeding element in string not working in JS

Tags: javascript, string, function

The question was to take a string and return the next letter in the alphabet for each letter of the string. For ex. "kick ass" should return "ljdl btt" 
I've written this code but it does not work. Perhaps someone can find my error(s)?

```
function LetterChanges(str) { 

  var LetterChanges = "";     
  var stringlength = str.length-1;
  var strAlpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  for (var i=0; i<strAlpha.length; i++) {
     if (strAlpha < strAlpha[i].length){
       LetterChanges += strAlpha[i] +1;
      }                
  return str; 
  } 
}

LetterChanges("hello there");
```

Comment: Why are you returning *that*?!

Comment: Your function doesn't look at the contents of `str`.

Comment: What are your boundary conditions (ie *z*)? What about capital letters, numbers, other characters?

Comment: What is your `if` statement's condition?

Comment: There are so many things wrong with your function. You're adding numbers to letters, you're comparing a string with its length, you're not using the argument, you're accumulating results in a variable, but you're not returning it. There's hardly anything right in it, you need to start all over again and think about what you're doing.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware I suck at this. But @Barmar at least you pointed out all the things I need to pay attention to! Thanks, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this easily with a regex and `replace`:

```
var str = 'kick azZ'.replace(/[a-z]/gi, function(c){
  if (c=='z') return 'a';
  if (c=='Z') return 'A';
  return String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
});

console.log(str); //= "ljdl baA"
```

Comment: @elclanrs will you solution scale with large strings? Regex don't work that well in terms of performance as far as my experience goes. I could be wrong.

Comment: (Having said that, we don't know what OP *wants* to do with corner cases)

Comment: @DavidHedlund: You're right about `z`. Edited the answer for that case. As for `.` it seems like it's not needed given that OP specified alphabet only.

Comment: Sure, it's unspecified at this point, but we could imagine that OP wants punctuation to be left intact, as is known to be the case for strings. That could of course be fixed with `/[a-z]/gi`. I'm not downvoting or anything, just leaving it as a comment for OP.

Comment: I reduce the code a bit more and you're right, `[a-z]` fits better.

Comment: @Tushar: [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/js-regex-replace). The regular iteration here is about twice as fast. Given a string over 4000 characters long, this still evaluates more than 1000 times per second, so OP should consider whether such use cases are an issue before opimizing prematurely.

Comment: Yes, iterating will be faster. I reverted to the version that was tested for convenience, since it's probably faster than 2 regex anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with your current function. Here's something a bit better for you to start with:

```
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz";

function translate(str) {
    var result = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var char = str.charAt(i);
        var index = alphabet.indexOf(char);

        // You'll have to find the next character in alphabet
        // Use the modulo operator (%) to handle "z" -> "a"

        result += nextChar;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice exercise! Check it out:

```
function LetterChanges(str) { 

  var result = [],
      strAlpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for(var i=str.length;i--;){
        var char = str[i],
            strIndex = strAlpha.indexOf(char),
            newIndex = (strIndex <  strAlpha.length-1) ? strIndex +1 : 0;

        result.unshift(strAlpha[newIndex]);
    }

    return result.join('');
}

alert(LetterChanges("hello there"));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H5Etv/1/

Maybe you only need to add some code the handle the space correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
function LetterChanges(str) { 

  var LetterChanges = "";     
  var stringlength = str.length-1;
  var strAlpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var n = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<stringlength; i++) {
     if(str[i] != ' ') {
     n=strAlpha.indexOf(str[i]);
     LetterChanges += strAlpha[n+1];
     }else{
     LetterChanges += ' ';
     }   
  }    
   return LetterChanges; 

}

document.write(LetterChanges("hello there"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to implement a function like this, but given what we've got here, it might be more instructive to address the part "perhaps someone can find my errors". Stepping through your code, there are more wrongs than rights, so it's not even clear what you've intended.

```
var stringlength = str.length-1;
```

This is weird, we don't know what you're trying to acheive here. `stringlength` is never used in the function:

```
for (var i=0; i<strAlpha.length; i++) {
```

You are iterating through the alphabet. I have a feeling you wanted to iterate your input argument `str`?

```
if (strAlpha < strAlpha[i].length){
```

This is weird as well. It's not clear what you're trying to test here. You're currently checking if the alphabet (a string, always the same value) is less than (i.e. comes before in alphabetical order) the `length` of the character at alphabet position `i`. Given that `i` is within the alphabet's range, `strAlpha[i]` will always return exactly one character. `strAlpha[i].length` can only ever be 1 or throw an exception. Now, since you're comparing your string to the numeric value `1`, the string compare will be a numeric less than condition. Your condition will pretty much always say `if('abc...' < 1)` which will never be true.

```
LetterChanges += strAlpha[i] +1;
```

If your code *did* enter the condition, it'd encounter this. Add `strAlpha[i]+1` to `LetterChanges`. Again, `strAlpha[i]` is the letter of the alphabet at the position `i`. For `i = 0`, `strAlpha[i] = 'a'`, and `'a' + 1 = 'a1'`. You're iterating through the entire alphabet; if your condition had evaluated to true, you'd end up with `LetterChanges = 'a1b1c1...'`. Here I'm going to assume you meant `strAlpha[i+1]` instead, which would yield the letter of the alphabet at the position `i+1`. You're still iterating through the entire alphabet and you'd end up shifting all characters one position up, `LetterChanges = 'bce...'`.

```
return str;
```

At last, you return the string. Here are two issues. The main one is that you return the input parameter `str` without having ever touched it. You'll always be returning whatever you passed to the function. Did you mean `return LetterChanges;`? The second concern is that you're returning it *inside* the `for` loop, which means that it'll exit the function at the first iteration, `i=0`, returning whatever was passed in.

If you changed to `return LetterChanges;` in this state, it'd return an empty string. If you changed the condition so that it evaluated to true and changed to `return LetterChanges;` it'd return `'b'`. If you did both those changes and moved the return statement outside the loop it'd return `'bcedefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'` regardless of what you passed.

There are so many issues here that we can't tell you what you should fix to get your code working. You need to step back and take a look at what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Modified eclanrs solution using string manipulation. Avoid this if the string is small (use regex, eclanrs solution).

```
var str = 'kick azz';
var rStr = "";
var t = str.split(' ');
for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
    var x = t[i];
    if (i > 0) {
        rStr += " ";
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
        var k = String.fromCharCode(x[j].charCodeAt(0) + 1);
        if (x[j] == "z") {
            k = "a";
        } else if (x[j] == "Z") {
            k = "A";
        }
        rStr += k;
    }
    t[i] = x;
}
str = rStr;
console.log(str); //= "ljdl btt"
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brFbm/)**

[jsperf](http://jsperf.com/regexvsstring1)